# array find duplicate values where a value repeats at a certain value

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array with dates:

```
Array ( [0] => 2019-10-01 [1] => 2019-10-03 [2] => 2019-10-04 [3] => 2019-10-04 [4] => 2019-11-01 [5] => 2019-11-01 [6] => 2019-11-01 [7] => 2019-11-02 [8] => 2019-11-04 )
```

I want to make a new array finding duplicate values but only when a value appears 3 times so the new array will look

```
Array ( [0] => 2019-11-01 )
```

any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array looks ordered, so you can iterate through and reset counter on any new value.

Otherwise, most likely you have to iterate through the array, so this is typical brute force solution:

```
$newArray = []
foreach($yourDateArray as $index => $date) {
    $newArray[$date][$index] = true;
}

$resultArray = []
foreach($newArray as $date => $list) {
    if(count($list) == 3) {
        $resultArray[] = $date;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$newArray = [];
// Count occurences of each value in array with `array_count_values`:
foreach(array_count_values($array) as $value => $count) {
    if ($count === 3) {
        $newArray[] = $value;
    }
}
```